# Catch javascript:window.close() inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, event-handling

I am running a third party HTML content inside an **iframe** that I have no control over, and in some cases they have links that call **javascript:window.close()** directly. Something like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:window.close()" value ="CLOSE">
```

I have no way of finding an ID or an array position of this element.

Naturally, it is ignored inside an iframe, but is there a way to catch when this event is fired? I tried

```
window.addEventListener("close", closeHandler, false);
window.addEventListener("onbeforeunload", closeHandler, false);
```

but it completely ignores it. Is there a way to somehow catch ALL JavaScript events/calls? Any recommendations are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to capture event inside the frame. If you cannot modify frame content then you might be out of luck. If you can modify iframe content then you could add that event listener on it and put it to call parent window's global function. Or you could try to use postMessage.